# C++: Avoiding dual maintenance in inheritance hierarchies

Tags: c++, dry, base-class

When creating a C++ inheritance structure, you have to define member functions exactly the same in multiple places:

If B is an abstract base class, and D, E, and F all inherit from B, you might have this:

```
class B
{
   virtual func A( ... params ) = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
   func A( ... params );
};

/* ... etc... similar implementations for E and F */
```

So, there is obviously some duplication here.  If the interface to B is large, you may have many places to change if the interface needs to change.

A coworker suggested some trickery with an embedded craftily-created #includes, ala:

```
class D: public B
{
   #include "B_Interface.h"  // B_Interface.h is a specially crafted .h file
}
```

This seems a little kludgy?  Is it?  Is there a better solution to avoid dual maintenance?

Also, maybe the solution here is really better tools to support the language, like Visual Assist X?

Edit:  Assume the derived classes must have unique implementations.

Comment: The Boost library actually does that at some parts, although not for inheritance, just for code reuse.

Comment: Why not using a macro rather than an include ? The point being that performance-wise `#include` implies looking up a file while a macro is already in the symbols table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, the biggest problem with changing an interface usually is all the code that *uses* it, not the code that implements it. If it's easy to change it for the implementer, it would probably make life harder for the users.

Comment: agreed -- IMHO and interface should be changed as little as possible so if it's a pain it's a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

That it's painful to change a widely used interface is not a bug; it's a feature.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, maybe the solution here is really better tools to support the language, like Visual Assist X?

Exactly. Changing method signatures is a [key feature](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/changeSignature.asp) of refactoring tools.

Comment: I second the recommendation. If you have to refactor C++ code, I found VAX pretty good. (And I found it pretty good for many other reasons, too.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to implement them over and over with some default behavior then maybe they should just be virtual, and not pure virtual.

Comment: In my particular case, there is a different implementation for each derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the preprocessor for yet another way it should not be used I'd try my editor (or IDE, if that's what you fancy.)